# mongo - couldn't connect to 127.0.0.1 - ip changed

Tags: mongodb, ip, localhost, database-connection

I installed mongoDB and changed the IP to 10.3.Y.XX.
When i want to start mongo from terminal (> mongo), this error occurs:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), 
connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does it work with the `10.3.x.y` IP?

Comment: how do i changed this? currently i justed changed the mongodb.conf

Comment: use the `--host` command line option: `mongo --host 10.3.x.y db_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect to something other than the default host (which is "localhost"), you need to tell your Mongo client application about it.

For example, on the command line you can do

```
mongo --host 10.3.x.y db_name
```